# How can I disable some hotkeys for Displaying? Such as ctrl+shift+keyDown

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

I want to use eclispse hotkey "ctrl+alt+down" to copy lines. But when I put the hotkey, my screen overturned. How can disable this hotkey in Windows7?

Answer (score 1):

This is a function  of your display driver. Check the graphics driver control panel or software and disable the hotkeys feature, or if it allows you to do so disable just this one hotkey.

Comment: I am thinkpad T420. But I can not find any place to disable these hotkeys in my  graphics driver control panel.

Comment: Looks like it has switchable graphics (Nvidia NVS 4200M / Intel Intregrated Graphics 3000). Did you check both the Nvidia and Intel graphics settings? Intel generally has settings like [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/72uzB.jpg) that you can disable, and if it's Nvidia's fault then they should have equivalent settings too.